# Php Mongodb Inserts empty string

Tags: php, mongodb

this is my code:

```
 $obj = array(
      'Cliente' => $cliente,
      'Label' => $label,
      'Imponibile' => $prezzo,
      'Importo' => $importo,
      'Iva' => $iva,
      'Mese' => date('m/Y')
   );
   var_dump($obj);


$temp_fatture->insert($obj);
```

var dump response is:

```
array (size=6)
  'Cliente' => string '565834968ff399361c1e825e' (length=24)
  'Label' => string 'Canone Indirizzo IP' (length=19)
  'Imponibile' => float 3
  'Importo' => float 3.66
  'Iva' => float 0.66
  'Mese' => string '12/2015' (length=7)
```

but when I go to check the document I placed only returns the variable $cliente, all other strings or numbers are null

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId("566d4daa8ff399e508829e8c"),
    'Cliente': '565834968ff399361c1e8975',
    'Label': '',
    'Imponibile': NumberLong(0),
    'Importo': 0,
    'Iva': 0,
    'Mese': '12/2015'
}
```

why do you think?